# Laravel Gates, how to use them in the API route?

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm defining my Gates for my API service in AuthServiceProvider (following the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#gates):

```
Gate::define('view-users', function ($user) {
   return $user->hasAccess(['view-users'])
   or $user->inRole(['admin', 'operator']);
});
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
        Route::get('/users', 'UserController@listing')->name('user.listing')->middleware(['can:view-users']);
});
```

How can I find the get the user from the Route API file to use in the Gate?

But I don't exactly understand where this `$user` is coming from. In my request I am sending an Authorization Bearer token. Should I be using this within my gate to fetch the correct user from the DB? How does Laravel know who `$user` is?

Answer (score 0):

The `$user` is the current logged in user. You do not need to provide the additional `$user`, Or pass the user in.

So if your app currently has a login user, that will be the one. If there is no login user the gate will return false which is protecting your resources.

Comment: I'm using an API, so the login is done through API tokens. I'd have to pass the `$user` in to the Gate somehow, ideally through the Route file.

Comment: @f7n , if there is a logged in user, you do not need to pass `$user`, laravel will resolve for you, use this code `auth()->user();` to check if you have a logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice from [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-gates) that Laravel provides the User for you in a Gate.

It says (emphasis mine):

> Gates are Closures that determine if a user is authorized to perform a given action and are typically defined in the App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider class using the Gate facade. **Gates always receive a user instance as their first argument.**

As Andy Song has pointed out in the comments, Laravel will resolve the User via Auth. If there *is* no user (not logged in, or no authentication), then, per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#guest-users):

> By default, all gates and policies **automatically return false** if the incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user.

If you want to trace how your user gets authenticated, your code snippet defines this middleware:

`'middleware' => ['auth:api']`

This uses the `auth` middleware, with `api` as a parameter. Your middleware is defined in `app/Http/Kernel.php`, and assuming you're using stock Laravel, it will then go on to authenticate your user, prior to your gate check taking place.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel doesn't know who the `$user` is. You need to pass it when you use the `Gate`. If you pass `Auth::user()` as a first argument of the `Gate` you are using, the code you wrote will work. In other cases, you will need to fetch the `user` from the Database with any given input.

Comment: So is it possible to use these gates in the Route?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: okay but in the Route how would I pass the user to the gate? I see in routes the gate should be used like this: `Route::middleware('can:isAdmin')`, without any params.

Comment: I usually use like this: `Gate::allows('example-action', Auth::user())`

Comment: I've updated my question with an example of my route.